# How to display the multiple images those are tagged already

Tags: php, jquery

Iam using image tagging and after tagging to an image Iam storing its positions x and y stored in DB..and while showing signle images with tagging it is displaying the correct position like

```
foreach($images_data as $img) {
     <img src="<?=$img['img']?>">
    <div class="tag" style="top:<?=$img['x']?>;left:<?=$img['y']?>;width:10px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
}
```

It is displaying the tag for first image is correct but from second image since it has stored with absolute positions they are displaying wrong.Can anyone tell me the correct way to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript/jQuery code here. By the way, multiple same IDs is a bad idea. About absolute positioning and `top`: what is wrong in second image (or its tag) displaying? You should provided rendered HTML as well.

Comment: @Regent I just sample the HTML and yes it is class not an ID

Comment: But can you show how this HTML code finally looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close it in relative positioned container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image"/>
    <div class="tag">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="image"/>
    <div class="tag">Text2</div>
</div>
```

HTML and CSS you have in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x7vpexc2/

Comment: Superb..I didnt thought this works but magically it done..thanku buddy